# How to call a gen-class method from clojure

Tags: java, clojure, compilation, call, gen-class

I'm Using gen-class to generate Java-classes from my Clojure code. In order to make gen-class work, I need to add an additional first parameter to all methods that will be added to the class (here called `this`).

```
(ns com.stackoverflow.clojure.testGenClass
  (:gen-class
     :name com.stackoverflow.clojure.TestGenClass
     :implements [com.stackoverflow.clojure.TestGenClassInterface]
     :prefix "java-"))

(def ^:private pre "START: ")

(defn java-addToString [this text post]
  (str pre text post))
```

After compilation, calling the method in a Java-context works fine.

```
(def var (com.stackoverflow.clojure.TestGenClass.))
(.addToString var "Aus Clojure heraus (Methode 1)." " :ENDE")
(. var addToString "Aus Clojure heraus (Methode 2)." " :ENDE")
```

But how can I start it directly from Clojure?

Thge following does not work, since the first parameter is missing.

```
(java-addToString "TexT" " :END")
```

Is it good practice to simply call the function with an empty first parameter?

```
(java-addToString "" "TexT" " :END")
```

Or should I add a function (e.g. `addToString`) that I use internally and call this function from the one that will be added as a method to the class-file?

Answer (score 0):

To want to treat the same code as a method on a generated class and as a function separate from said class seems a bit smelly to me (in the sense of code smell, something that indicates a problem somewhere in the design).

Perhaps `addToString` should be a static method?

Perhaps you should make an `add-to-string` function that can be used directly in clojure, and also called by the `addToString` method?

We'd need to know more about your larger design before we know the best answer, but I suspect it is one of those.